# Application gives Communications Link Failure on Mac OS while using MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, macos, jdbc

My application is using MySQL Server. When i try to launch it on Mac OS, the application state hangs at my persistence manager where i try to establish a connection. A exception is thrown after exactly 30 minutes.

2011-02-25 15:24:06,137 2292512 ERROR   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter    Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
2011-02-25 16:24:07,944 5894319 ERROR   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter    Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
2011-02-25 16:24:07,945 5894320 ERROR   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter    Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
2011-02-25 16:24:07,947 5894322 ERROR   com.agilent.cgh.dal.persistence.AbstractPersistenceType 
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection : Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1353)

After a bit of debugging i found that the application hangs in my Spring Framework while loading beanRefContext.xml

Any ideas why the application is unable to start on Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can take a look to mySql configuration file

/etc/my.cnf

probabilly if I've understood well your request the problem is here:

```
wait_timeout = 1800
connect_timeout = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at "max_connections" line. In case you're using connection pooling it can grow faster than expected and get to the limit amount of connections, giving this lines you mentioned as a result.